# VB.NET Credits System

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a Mysql database setup:

Table Accounts:

Id: 1
Name: Donny
Credits: 600

I have a button named Buy
And the following runs when clicked

```
If credits.Text <= 0 Then
            MsgBox("Geen credits meer.")
        Else

            Dim conn As MySqlConnection
            conn = New MySqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = "server=xxx;port=3306; user id=xxx; password=xxx; database=xxx"
            Try
                conn.Open()
            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("error connecting to database")
            End Try
            Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

            Dim sqlquery = "UPDATE account SET credits = credits -700 WHERE id='" & Trim(id.Text) & "'"

            Dim mycommand As New MySqlCommand()
            mycommand.Connection = conn
            mycommand.CommandText = sqlquery
            myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
            mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Try
                conn.Close()
            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
            Finally
                conn.Dispose()
            End Try

        End If
```

For example, I have 600 credits on my account. And I want to buy a product that costs 700. The system says its not possible because you got only 600 credits. The current code shows -100 credits, but how can I check and show an error message instead?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a stored procedure to perform this operation with a return value indicating success or failure. Check for available credits and debit the amount (if sufficient credits exist) within a transaction.

Comment: I guess you should READ the available credit first, then validate if it is sufficient, if not pop-up message, else proceed to update!

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a function to your program to check if there are enough credits:

```
Public Function checkCredits(ByVal creditsNeeded As Int32, ByVal id As String) As Boolean
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=xxx;port=3306; user id=xxx; password=xxx; database=xxx"
    conn.Open()

    Dim mycommand As New MySqlCommand()
    With mycommand
        .Connection = conn
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = "SELECT credits FROM account WHERE id = @id"
        .Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id
    End With

    Dim creditsAvailable As Int32 = mycommand.ExecuteScalar
    conn.Close()

    If creditsAvailable >= creditsNeeded Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

And then adjust your code above to use it:

```
If credits.Text <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("Geen credits meer.")
    Else
        If checkCredits(700, id.Text) Then

            Dim conn As MySqlConnection
            conn = New MySqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = "server=xxx;port=3306; user id=xxx; password=xxx; database=xxx"
            Try
                conn.Open()
            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("error connecting to database")
            End Try
            Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

            Dim sqlquery = "UPDATE account SET credits = credits -700 WHERE id='" & Trim(id.Text) & "'"

            Dim mycommand As New MySqlCommand()
            mycommand.Connection = conn
            mycommand.CommandText = sqlquery
            myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
            mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Try
                conn.Close()
            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
            Finally
                conn.Dispose()
            End Try
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Credits")
        End If
    End If
```